# Importing Text File For Conways Game Of Life

Tags: python, python-2.7, conways-game-of-life

I am trying to import a text file to use as a board in Conway's game of life,  I have 2 functions,  one to read the file,  the pretty print,  to print the board out so it's user friendly.  Can someone spot where I am going wrong? This is for python 2.7.

```
def read_game_board(game_file):
    board = open('grid0.txt')
    game_file = board.readlines()
    return 

def pretty_print(b):
    pretty_len = len(b)
    for x in range(0, pretty_len):
        for y in range(pretty_len):
            print [x][y]
        print '/n'

def main(name_of_file):
    b = read_game_board(board)
    run_game()
```

This is what the text file looks like:

```
----------
----------
---xx-----
---xx-----
----------
----------
----------
----------
----------
----------
```

Comment: What's the problem you want help with? Is it not printing out the board? If that's the problem, you don't pass the contents you read from the file to your `pretty_print` function.

Comment: `b = read_game_board(board)`. But board isn't defined yet. It won't exist until `board = open('grid0.txt')` executes, and even then it will only be accessible inside the `read_game_board` function, not `main`. Also, you never do anything with `name_of_file`, and there's no point passing `game_file` as a parameter if you assign something else to that name without ever looking at the original value.

Comment: In the `read_game_board()` function the variable `game_file` is a local variable and its contents are lost when the function returns. Change it to `return game_file.splitlines()` which will return the value to the caller (after stripping the newlines at the end of each one).